# Access value from a custom annotation on a field

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Let's say I have the following `Page Factory` based code

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "cancel_action")
@CustomLog("Cancel Button")
public MobileElement btnCancel;

@AndroidFindBy(id = "ok_action")
@CustomLog("ok Button")
public MobileElement btnOk;


public void tap(MobileElement element) {
    element.tap(1, 500);
    //add the reflection code to print the value of CustomLog annotation
}
```

Now if I call the tap method as below it should print the value of "CustomLog" annotation of `btnCancel`

```
tap(btnCancel);
```

I will be able to `tap` on the specified `MobileElement` `element` successfully as it knows it has to tap on `id = "cancel_action"` using the annotation `@AndroidFindBy`
Now if I want to access the Custom Annotation (`@CustomLog`) value which is "Cancel Button" in my test is it possible? I created an annotation called "CustomLog" But how do I access the value of this annotation as part of this `MobileElement`

Comment: You can use reflection to access annotations, although what do you want to do with this?

Comment: @mrfreester: I know I can use `reflection`. However I want the value in the `@CustomLog` tagged to the specific `field`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of your custom annotation ("Cancel Button") at runtime, reflection is the way to go.

First of all, make sure that your annotation has the rention `RUNTIME`, as otherwise it won't be there anymore once the code is compiled:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public static @interface MyAnnotation {
  String value();
}
```

Then you can use your annotation like you already have:

```
@MyAnnotation("test")
public MobileElement element;
```

And simply retrieve the annotation of that specific field `Field`:

```
Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("element");
```

And get the `value()` from the annotation:

```
MyAnnotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(annotation.value());
```

So in my example, that would print "test" to the console.

Comment: I have updated my question. I know I can access the value of the annotation that way. But my question is if there are 100's of such fields with that annotation. How do I get the annotation of that specific field

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have the problem that your "tap" method gets a MobileElement, and you want to find out whether that MobileElement is the "btnOk" or the "btnCancel" then (in order to retrieve the annotation from the right field)?

Comment: Let's say the `tap` method get's the right `MobileElement` for example `tap(btnCancel);`. Now if I want to get the value of `@CustomLog` for this particular `btnCancel` field or as a matter of fact, anything that's passed to `tap` method. For eg, if I use `tap(btnCancel)` and if the `tap` method has a logging implementation to read the `CustomLog` annotation's `value`.. this logging implementation should log "Cancel Button". similarly if `tap(btnOk)` is used. It should log "Ok Button"

Comment: Ok, I see.Well,that's not going to work, really. `btnCancel` in the case when tap(...) is called is just a pointer to an object that lives somewhere in memory. There's no easy way to identify that this pointer is stored in a field which has a `@CustomLog` annotation. In fact, that pointer could be stored in different fields in different objects of different classes, and `@CustomLog` could have different values every time.
I think what you want to do is either introduce a `tapCancel()` method and a `tapOk()` method or introduce a `tap` method with an enum parameter that you can use for logging

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks buddy. I'll +1 the post as it is very close to something that I require.